# sqlite - How can I order in group but randomly?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, random

Let`s say I have a table with one column being:

```
Letter  
A
B
B
C
A
A
C
```

I'm trying to make a query which would return these letters **`in order`** but in a **`random order`**, like first all the C's then all the A's, etc. Example:

```
Letter  
C
C
A
A
A
B
B
```

So the letters would show up together, but in a random order each time I queried it. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select letter, rand() as rnd
      from t
      group by letter
     ) tt
     on t.letter = tt.letter
order by tt.rnd;
```

A simpler method uses computation on letter itself.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
order by rand(ascii(t.letter));
```

This is canonical, so running it twice in a row returns the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**`For MySQL:`**

```
SELECT T.Letter 
FROM Your_Table T
JOIN (
    SELECT *
        ,RAND()RandumNum
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT Letter FROM Your_Table
        )D
        )E ON E.Letter = T.Letter
ORDER BY E.RandumNum
```

Check this [#1 SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd96cda/1)

**`For Sqlite:`**

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tempEmployees AS 
SELECT Letter,RANDOM()RandumNum 
FROM Your_Table
GROUP BY Letter
;

SELECT T.Letter
FROM Your_Table T
JOIN tempEmployees E ON E.Letter = T.Letter
ORDER BY E.RandumNum;
```

Check this [#2 SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fd96c/16)

Comment: Works nice, but it can be done with 2 selects instead of 3 as shown by Gordon Linoff in his answer